# Laravel, can't acces to object data

Tags: php, laravel, class-visibility

I have this output at `print_r($mailable)`:

```
Illuminate\Mail\SendQueuedMailable Object
(
    [mailable:protected] => App\Mail\Expired Object
        (
            [user:protected] => App\User Object
                (
                    [fillable:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => name
                            [1] => email
                            [2] => password
                            [3] => demo
                            [4] => email_demo
                        )

                    [hidden:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => password
                            [1] => remember_token
                        )

                    [connection:protected] => 
                    [table:protected] => 
                    [primaryKey:protected] => id
                    [keyType:protected] => int
                    [perPage:protected] => 15
                    [incrementing] => 1
                    [timestamps] => 1
                    [attributes:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1020
```

How can I acces to that last line `[id] => 1020`?

I tried with $mailable->user, $mailable->mailable, but it says:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Mail\SendQueuedMailable::$user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties you need are `protected`, so you can't access them from the outside, and [the API](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Mail/SendQueuedMailable.php) does not offer getter methods. Since version 5.4, Laravel have made these properties `public`.

I'd recommend either updating to a newer version of Laravel, writing your own custom class that adds an accessor method, or use the [pry bar technique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php#120150) to force the protected variables into the public API.